# What is the path to set the user comment field of exif using CGImageMetadataSetTagWithPath?

Tags: ios

What is the path to set the user comment field of exif using CGImageMetadataSetTagWithPath?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/1465409-cgimagemetadatasettagwithpath

Answer (score 2):

It works with `exif:UserComment`:

```
guard let tag = CGImageMetadataTagCreate(
    kCGImageMetadataNamespaceExif,
    kCGImageMetadataPrefixExif,
    kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment,
    .string,
    "my exif comment" as CFString) else { fatalError("Metadata tag not created") }

let metadata = CGImageMetadataCreateMutable()

CGImageMetadataSetTagWithPath(
    metadata,
    nil,
    "exif:UserComment" as CFString,
    tag)
```

---

**EDIT**

At the time of writing, if one wants documentation for ImageIO functions, one should Cmd-click on each of these functions. It seems its format wasn't updated and therefore doesn't show in Xcode or their web interface (developer.apple.com).

We have more info on how a path is formed in the documentation for the `CGImageMetadataCopyTagWithPath` function. Extract:

> A string representing a path to the desired tag. Paths consist of a tag prefix (i.e. "exif") joined with a tag name (i.e. "Flash") by a colon (":"), such as CFSTR("exif:Flash").

Instead of hardcoding the value we can use the following code:

```
let path = "\(kCGImageMetadataPrefixExif):\(kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment)" as CFString
```